# Group By 2 columns specifically

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(TranAmount * -1) [RecVal],
    ISNULL(SC.CountryName,
        (SELECT tblSysCountry.CountryName 
         FROM tblIdcBranchMaster 
         INNER JOIN tblSysCountry ON tblIDCBranchMaster.countryID = tblSysCountry.CountryId 
         WHERE tblIDCBranchMaster.idcBranchID = TM.idcBranchID)
    ) [Country]
FROM 
    tblDebtorTransactionMaster TM
LEFT JOIN 
    tblIDCEmployeeMaster EM ON EM.employeeID = TM.employeeWorkedBy
LEFT JOIN 
    tblIDCBranchMaster BM ON EM.homeBranch = BM.idcBranchCode
LEFT JOIN 
    tblSysCountry SC ON SC.CountryId = BM.countryID
WHERE 
    TM.tranTypeID IN (2, 6, 7, 18, 9, 11, 51)
    AND TM.documentDate BETWEEN dbo.default_date_format('**INPUT DATE**') 
    AND dbo.default_date_format('**INPUT DATE**')
GROUP BY 
    SC.CountryName,TM.idcBranchID
```

*Dates removed for security purposes*

The problem is I want to be able to group completely by the second column not just by country name.

Currently I link the country to a branch which is linked to an employee who processed the transaction, but if the transaction was process automatically then I need to check to what branch the account links to (each transaction links to a branch).

The branch that the employee links to *CAN DIFFER* from the branch that the transaction links to if an employee from a different branch captures that transaction.

When I run the query above my results are as follows: I need to ultimately see how much money was collected for each country (Not the branch)

```
RecVal      +   Country
80090.42    +   SOUTHAFRICA
181248.10   +   SOUTHAFRICA
140989.16   +   SOUTHAFRICA
21854.01    +   SOUTHAFRICA
53037.25    +   SOUTHAFRICA
84241.62    +   SOUTHAFRICA
49598.07    +   SOUTHAFRICA
200.00      +   SOUTHAFRICA
75559.36    +   SOUTHAFRICA
12.91       +   SOUTHAFRICA
35784.91    +   SOUTHAFRICA
28627.04    +   SOUTHAFRICA
500.00      +   SOUTHAFRICA
22688.04    +   SOUTHAFRICA
38443.02    +   SOUTHAFRICA
34313.16    +   SOUTHAFRICA
62419.27    +   SOUTHAFRICA
50.00       +   SOUTHAFRICA
73598.95    +   SOUTHAFRICA
86741.78    +   SOUTHAFRICA
21553.98    +   SOUTHAFRICA
12.40       +   SOUTHAFRICA
86673.27    +   SOUTHAFRICA
48021.07    +   SOUTHAFRICA
22586.55    +   SOUTHAFRICA
11027.50    +   SOUTHAFRICA
14897.55    +   SOUTHAFRICA
49672.86    +   SOUTHAFRICA
14910.98    +   SOUTHAFRICA
6152.10     +   SOUTHAFRICA
91878.14    +   SOUTHAFRICA
47132.15    +   SOUTHAFRICA
24957.49    +   SOUTHAFRICA
93.25       +   SOUTHAFRICA
54657.67    +   SOUTHAFRICA
71687.30    +   SWAZILAND
740.00      +   SOUTHAFRICA
607419.67   +   NAMIBIA
150.00      +   SOUTHAFRICA
160.49      +   SOUTHAFRICA
522544.70   +   SOUTHAFRICA
300.00      +   SOUTHAFRICA
13207.29    +   SOUTHAFRICA
47090.91    +   SOUTHAFRICA
51591.77    +   SOUTHAFRICA
600.00      +   SOUTHAFRICA
45605.71    +   SOUTHAFRICA
5642.54     +   SOUTHAFRICA
1470.00     +   NAMIBIA 
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the code in a CTE (Common Table Expression). You need to start the with with a preceding ; if you have sql codethat exists beforehand. I see you have a lot of South African transactions. Fellow Saffa here.

```
;WITH Base AS (SELECT SUM(TranAmount * -1) [RecVal],
    ISNULL(SC.CountryName,
    (
        SELECT tblSysCountry.CountryName 
        FROM tblIdcBranchMaster 
            INNER JOIN tblSysCountry ON tblIDCBranchMaster.countryID =  tblSysCountry.CountryId 
        WHERE tblIDCBranchMaster.idcBranchID = TM.idcBranchID
    )
) [Country]
FROM tblDebtorTransactionMaster TM
LEFT JOIN tblIDCEmployeeMaster EM ON EM.employeeID = TM.employeeWorkedBy
LEFT JOIN tblIDCBranchMaster BM ON EM.homeBranch = BM.idcBranchCode
LEFT JOIN tblSysCountry SC ON SC.CountryId = BM.countryID
WHERE TM.tranTypeID IN (2, 6, 7, 18, 9, 11, 51)
AND TM.documentDate BETWEEN dbo.default_date_format('**INPUT DATE**') 
AND dbo.default_date_format('**INPUT DATE**')
GROUP BY SC.CountryName,TM.idcBranchID
) 

SELECT Sum(RecVal) as SumRecVal,Country FROM Base GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked thanks I just had to sum the value in the Actual select but Thanks. Lol Im glad to see Im not the only Saffa here ...

Comment: Thanks dude for pointing the sum out. I think there are a few of us out here, just not many active on StackOverflow. Trying to get some points, would be cool to build rep. Keep well.